# flutter - HTML file in WebViewController not loading as expected in iOS Simulator

Tags: ios, flutter, dart, webview, ios-simulator

Below the code loads several tweets in WebViews. This code works flawlessly in Android but produces a different result in iOS Simulator. No errors are produced in logs and nothing in flutter analyze pertain to this page and its classes.

Included `<key>io.flutter.embedded_views_preview</key><true/>` in info.plist

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    var child;
    //print(_tweetHTML);
    if (_tweetHTML != '' && _tweetHTML.length > 0) {
      final downloadUrl = Uri.file(_filename).toString();
      print(downloadUrl); //This prints the expected HTML file
      // Create the WebView to contian the tweet HTML
      final webView = WebView(
          initialUrl: downloadUrl,
          javascriptMode: JavascriptMode.unrestricted,
      
        gestureNavigationEnabled: true,
          navigationDelegate: (NavigationRequest request) {

            if (request.url.startsWith(downloadUrl)) {
              //print('allowing navigation to $request');
              return NavigationDecision.navigate;
            } else if (request.isForMainFrame) {
              //print('allowing navigation to $request');
              _launchURL(request.url);
              return NavigationDecision.prevent;
            } else {
              //print('blocking navigation to $request}');
              return NavigationDecision.prevent;
            }
        },);

      final box = LimitedBox(
        maxHeight: 500.0,
        child: webView,
      );

      child = box;
    } else {
      child = Text('Loading...');
    }

    return Container(child: child);
  }
```

Expected results:

As you can see this works in Android:
[image: ANDROID]

Actual results:

However on iOS:
[image: iOS]

Comment: Does your html file contain necessary css or is it blocked by CORS policy?

Comment: I clicked it and it open in a browser correctly. It's an individual tweet from the Twitter API

Answer (score 0):

**Option 1:** add this to html body

```html
<script id="twitter-wjs" type="text/javascript" async defer src="//platform.twitter.com/widgets.js"></script>
```

**Option 2:** Check out this widget on github [TweetWebView for Flutter](https://github.com/larryaasen/tweet_webview)

**Option 3:** use  [Flutter WebView Plugin](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_webview_plugin) by fluttercommunity.dev, **BUT** This webview is not integrated in the widget tree, it is a native view on top of the flutter view. You won't be able see snackbars, dialogs, or other flutter widgets that would overlap with the region of the screen taken up by the webview.

Comment: I've found the main problem is the navigationDelegate. Without the navigationDelegate it works fine, but I need the navigationDelegate so that if the user clicks inside the webview it opens in an external browser.

Comment: @KristinVernon did you manage  to do this?

Comment: I've looked over your solutions but none of them quite fits my problem. I need a way to use webview and open the links externally in ios without using navigation delegate.

Comment: If you open the html in a chrome on PC or Mac, does it work? Or it gives you CORS error?

Comment: Yes the html works when opening in MAC